# Allow only html break tag with regex

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

I have the following preg_match statment in php:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\d '-^\",.!?]+$/", $cont)){ 
    //do something 
}
```

In addition I want to allow br tags but no other html tags, how can I do that?

Also is it done the same way with JS?

```
var cCheck = /^[0-9a-zA-Z '-^\",.!?]+$/;

if(!Cont.match(cCheck)){ 
    //do something 
}
```

Comment: `if($cont !== strip_tags($cont, '<br>')) { //bad }`

Comment: Escape the `-` or move it to the start or end of character class. As is that is looking for a range between `'` and `^`. This thread might be useful for JS usage. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392931/how-do-i-strip-all-html-tags-in-javascript-with-exceptions